# How to incrementally parse JSON from a websocket message in Python?

Tags: python, json, websocket

I have JSON messages (JSON hash table) represented as strings coming in through a websocket. Each read from the socket may return a string that does not end on a message boundary. What's the easiest way to parse the JSON messages in Python? How do I find where in the string a message terminates without writing a parser (or brace/paren matcher) myself?

Do other languages provide tools to make this easier?

Comment: you could use `try .. except ..` to parse merged strings until a successful JSON object is parsed

Comment: please provide some json format you want read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each read from the socket may return a string that does not end on a message boundary.

This is incorrect - Websockets is a message oriented protocol as opposed to the traditional stream oriented TCP socket protocol where you needed to worry about and handle message chunking.

It is built on top of TCP, however it automatically handles piecing the individual fragments into [one complete message](http://timkellogg.me/blog/2015/03/01/websockets-are-not-magic/) before delivering it at the application layer (your code).

> So websockets are message-oriented like UDP without the maximum length constraints but with TCP’s delivery guarantees and congestion control. It turns out that TCP’s stream orientation isn’t all that useful (think about how many protocols build some sort of “message” concept on top of TCP). In fact SCTP (RFC 4960) provides many of the same benefits of messages-on-top-of-TCP but removes the TCP part to reduce the overhead. Unfortunately, SCTP is yet to gain widespread adoption.

Also from the [official RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> layers a framing mechanism on top of TCP to get back to the IP packet mechanism that TCP is built on, but without length limits